# Rails is it good or bad practice to test small methods in models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have  model:

```
 class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base

  def pending_edits
    self.edits.where(:is_approved => nil)
  end

  def update_body (new_body)
    update_attributes :old_body => self.body, :body => new_body
  end

  def current_accepted_edit
    edits.find_by(:is_current => true)
  end
```

**1) Is it overkill and bad practice to test this methods since there are so simple ?**

But I wrote tests for them anyway.So just in case

**2)If I need to test them -  Is it a good `it block description` :** in my rspec test?

```
it 'answer.pending edits_method' do
 some testing code
end
```

Comment: It really depends, do you think this really small spec adds something usesfull you your test suite? if the answer is yes: do it, if the answer is no: don't do it, if you can't decide: do it anyway, if you are not sure better to have it than don't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should test all of your public methods irrespective of size.  So if the method can be called from outside of the class then you test it.  That said don't test private/protected methods if they are used as composition for public api methods. Edit in response to your edit:  I would do

```
it "returns pending edits" do
end
```